# how to read /data/anr/traces.txt from code in android?

Tags: android, file, crash, reporting, trace

I am working on crash reporting in android. For this, I need to access traces.txt file from code.
I already know how to access this file in commandline with adb pull command.
But I need to acces this file in application.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Best to my knowledge, `traces.txt` can be accessed in code via:

Open file with this path:

```
(Your Package)/traces.txt
```

Comment: Thanks @SaneSpeaker will try this out. Atleast you came up with something after a long time.

Comment: what would be the value of (your package)? I tried /data/data/mypackagename and adding /files to that, but no joy. And from the cli, the file is in /data/anr/.

Answer (score 1):

I successfully got the traces with `"data/anr/traces.txt"` path. One thing to note is that this file might not be present in the directory until your app actually experiences an ANR. At least that was my case.

Also, my app requests a permission to access an internal storage, but I'm not sure if that matters.